# Failed to import a 3D object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, computer-vision, rendering, render

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-obj.html) to import `windmill.obj` in THREE.js. But I got "THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D".

As you can see, `cube` can be shown, but the `windmill.obj` doesn't show.

Any ideas why the tutorial can import the file without any error, but the same file is not recognized as the THREE.Object3D in my code? Thanks

```
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>


<script type="module">
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {OBJLoader2} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js';


let scene, renderer, camera
let cube
let rotateHeadOffset = 0


function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene()
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100)
  camera.position.set(10, 10, 10)
  camera.lookAt(scene.position)

  // cube
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1))
  scene.add(cube)

  // instantiate the loader
  let loader = new OBJLoader2();
  function callbackOnLoad ( object3d ) {
    scene.add( object3d );
  }
  loader.load("https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/windmill/windmill.obj", callbackOnLoad, null, null, null );

}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

init()
render()

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I got "THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D"

Comment: Your example is importing parts of the three.js library from two different sources — this won't work, you need to use the same source and three.js version for everything. See the CDN examples here: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Comment: Thanks for help. `import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';
` works.